# Sticky column creates stacked stacking contexts

Tags: css, z-index, sticky

I have a table with a sticky column.
When I view at this table in a 3d viewer, I can see every column has a higher z-index than the column before.
So when I want to use a dropdown in this column, it is always covered by the column on the next line.

```css
td {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.fixed-column {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  background-color: white;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  background: #0080ff;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
      <th>Col 4</th>
      <th>Col 5</th>
      <th>Col 6</th>
      <th>Col 7</th>
      <th>Col 8</th>
      <th>Col 9</th>
      <th class="fixed-column">Col 10</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 2 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 3 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 4 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 5 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 6 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 7 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 8 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 9 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td class="fixed-column">
        <button type="button">Menu</button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <ul>
            <li>Option 1</li>
            <li>Option 2</li>
            <li>Option 3</li>
            <li>Option 4</li>
            <li>Option 5</li>
            <li>Option 6</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- ... -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is a plnkr with an example: http://plnkr.co/plunk/CqqeSWIQrSsSVJB3

Here you can see a screenshot of the 3d viewer:
[image]

Is there any way to prevent the browser to stack all these sticky cells on the z-axis so that the dropdown menu (the blue div-container) will show on top of all these cells?

Comment: so what does you really want & how you want to look your page ....please be specific

Comment: I want to have the dropdown menu on top of all of these sticky cells

Comment: Please update your question to clearly demonstrate "`So when I want to use a dropdown in this column" What dropdown, I see no dropdown/select element?  What column specifically, the one you have as "sticky?> (kind of feels like that should NOT be in a column of a table but a separate element set on your page outside the table.  Do you mean when you add more rows the problem exists/exhibits here?  IF that is the crux of the issue you need more rows to illustrate this undesired behavior in your question more clearly.

Comment: Okay, I just simplified this as an example. In every row of the table should be a menu for different actions on this row (show more details, edit, delete and so on). My dropdown menu is not a select-element, it is a webcomponent, which has in its simplest form a button and a div-container. The div-container is dynamically positioned with position: fixed. I have reproduced the behaviour with the element with classname ".dropdown-menu". The problem is, that the div-container is not fully visible, because the the sticky td-element of the next row is on top of it and covers the dropdown-element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve that, provided you can dynamically set a class on the cell that's displaying the menu, is to set a z-index for this particular cell, which will have it rendered over the next ones:

```css
td {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.fixed-column {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  background-color: white;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  background: #0080ff;
}

.withmenu {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
      <th>Col 4</th>
      <th>Col 5</th>
      <th>Col 6</th>
      <th>Col 7</th>
      <th>Col 8</th>
      <th>Col 9</th>
      <th class="fixed-column">Col 10</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 2 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 3 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 4 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 5 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 6 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 7 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 8 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 9 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td class="fixed-column withmenu">
        <button type="button">Menu</button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <ul>
            <li>Option 1</li>
            <li>Option 2</li>
            <li>Option 3</li>
            <li>Option 4</li>
            <li>Option 5</li>
            <li>Option 6</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 2 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 3 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 4 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 5 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 6 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 7 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 8 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 9 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td class="fixed-column">
        <button type="button">Menu</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 2 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 3 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 4 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 5 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 6 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 7 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 8 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 9 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td class="fixed-column">
        <button type="button">Menu</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 2 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 3 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 4 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 5 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 6 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 7 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 8 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 9 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td class="fixed-column">
        <button type="button">Menu</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 2 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 3 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 4 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 5 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 6 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 7 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 8 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 9 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td class="fixed-column">
        <button type="button">Menu</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 2 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 3 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 4 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 5 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 6 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 7 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 8 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 9 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td class="fixed-column">
        <button type="button">Menu</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 2 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 3 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 4 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 5 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 6 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 7 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 8 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 9 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td class="fixed-column">
        <button type="button">Menu</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 2 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 3 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 4 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 5 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 6 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 7 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 8 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td>Cell 9 content with a lot of text ...</td>
      <td class="fixed-column">
        <button type="button">Menu</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Another solution would be to take the menu out of the `<td>` and assign a z-index to it, but then it would require dynamic positioning... So not a better solution.